# Who's that Pokémon?

Tags: character-identification, pokemon

My kids received some Pokémon themed bath bombs that contained mini Pokémon inside that become exposed when the water dissolves the rest of the bath bomb. So far, we've gotten slowpoke, lapras, caterpie, croconaw, wigglytuff, and this green guy. I can't identify him through online resources. Does anyone know which Pokémon this represents?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Man, you surely have a natural talent for getting the focus wrong!

Comment: Well, one-handed close-ups will do that. The phone focuses on a specific part of the object, making the rest out of focus.

Comment: @Ellesedil For future reference, generally the trick is to move the phone further away, take the shot, and then crop to size.

Comment: I think it's sweet that you've invented some kids to cover up the fact that you bought yourself some fizzy pokemon bath bombs.

Comment: Are the others a more fitting color?

Comment: @motoDrizzt: Without [focus stacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_stacking), the depth of field is so shallow that you have to get the focus wrong somewhere.

Comment: @jpmc26 yes, more or less.

Comment: @EricDuminil Yes, but clearly, you want the focus on the object the question is about, rather than on the table it's sitting on.

Comment: @jpmc26: It's not that easy. On each picture, there are in and out of focus parts for both the toy and the table. It's not possible to have the whole toy in focus at this distance, and at this angle, there will always be a part of the table which is in focus.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

That's Dialga, a 4th Generation Pokémon and the poster Pokémon of Pokémon Diamond.

[image: Dialga]

Comment: I appreciate that we have just literally played "Who is that Pokémon?"

Comment: Well, the green of the toy really threw me off. Also doesn't help that I competely skipped 4th gen both in the game and anime.

Comment: @boiko Dialga never appeared on the "Who's That Pokémon" segment, so I could not add a clip of it.

Comment: my kingdom for someone with gimp/photoshop skills!

Comment: @WayneWerner for what? To turn it green? https://ibb.co/dCJgWT

Comment: @motoDrizzt to put this green jelly Dialga-thing in the "Who's that Pokémon" screen

Comment: Considering that it appears one of the other Pokemon we got was a Mega Mewtwo Y, I'm going to assume that the green Dialga is supposed to be it's shiny version.

Comment: @Ellesedil Consider it could also be a limitation of the materials used to make thse bath bombs.

Answer (score 3):

It can be just Dialga. But due to its color and the blade coming out from its right foot, I am guessing it may not be a typical one, but a fusion (offspring) of Scyther and Dialga. From [here](http://pokefusion.japeal.com/) it even has a name of Scylga, though it is not standard.

[image]

However, if just based on apperance but not its blade, it can just the offspring of metapod and Dialga.:
[image]

Or it can be a [shiny](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shiny_Pok%C3%A9mon) Dialga (again if just from apperance):
[image]

Comment: The other pokemon he identified as being standard pokemon from the show. It's highly unlikely that a licensed multi-pack would contain a fansmash pokemon.

Comment: It is unlikely, but there are indeed many pokemon toys like mudsaur: "https://www.shapeways.com/product/7Z7SQZNTE/mudsaur-pokemon-fusion" so there is indeed a chance. But i agree thats not very likely but a mistake of the product manufacturer.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? Dialga is blue. This bath bomb is green. Even if this was a mistake of the manufacturer, the pokemon shown in the question isn't blue.

Comment: That's not a licensed product. It's made by someone called Fan Bas3D Designs on a 3D printer then painted

Comment: @Frank - I downvoted due to the unlikeliness of this being the correct answer. The pokemon above isn't an official pokemon, it's a fan creation.

Comment: Also, the "blade" in the foot that you mention is just excess plastic during the creation process that was never trimmed. There is absolutely no design to it whatsoever.

Comment: I'd upvote if this answer just suggested 'shiny Dialga', but I'm afraid the fakemons get a -1.